# Call remote servers using a google cloud product

Tags: cloud, xml, json

I have the following use case that I was trying to find a google solution for. I wanted to be able to call a remote server to get some data. The data comes back as XML. Then I wanted to extract specific parts of the XML and put that into a JSON structure which then would be put into a Cloud Storage bucket. I guess I am looking for a product that can call a function to retrieve the data, then another function to extract the data, another to put the data into a JSON structure and lastly, put the JSON into a bucket. Can anyone help point me to some Cloud solutions that could do this for me? I've looked into Dataflow and Pub/Sub but they seem to simple for this job although I could be misunderstanding these products.

Comment: For the first part, you can use XSLT to transform XML into anything else.

Comment: Thank you Jos, I'm going down that path. I've just looked at Cloud Functions would that be the best place to write up the code?

Comment: I don't know, I have no experience with that. In any case once you have created the right XSLT file it just takes a single command to write the JSON file.